# Storing user's up/downvoted posts

Tags: sql, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following schema, where an AppUser can have many UserPosts (the user's own posts) and also can upvote/downvote other users' posts too.

```
public class AppUser {
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Post> UserPosts {get; set;}

    public ICollection<Post> UpvotedPosts {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Post> DownvotedPosts {get;set;}
}

public class Post {
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Content {get;set;}

    public string AppUserId {get;set;}
    public AppUser AppUser {get;set;}
}
```

I'm trying to work out the relationship between the Up/Down voted posts and the AppUser. I think it should be 1 to many (1 app user can have many up/downvote posts - and each post can only have one AppUser).

But with this line of thinking, it causes conflict with the UserPosts - since I've also defined that 1 AppUser can have many posts while a post can have only 1 user.

What is the recommended way of going about this?

Comment: Think of it... One post can be several times up-voted or down-voted. So, It should be another table for upvotes/downvotes. That means, that the relationship is many to many. `1 AppUser - &infin; Vote --- Vote &infin; -  1 Post`. Many users can vote for many posts of another user.

Comment: I do have a separate table for UserVotes, where I store the UserId, PostId, and Up/Downvote (1 or 0). To get all the up/down votes for the logged in user, are you saying I can simply query that table with the the UserID?

Comment: No. I'm saying that the relationship is many to many ;)

Comment: Do you mean 1 User can have many votes and one post can have many votes too? Since the common item between User and Post is vote, which is present in both the relationships, votes needs its own table as well?

Comment: Exactly! This is what i've stated for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a many-to-many relationship between `AppUser` and `Post`. You can introduce an entity called `Vote` to represent the many-to-many relationship.

The following fully working console sample demonstrates this approach:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public class AppUser
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Post> UserPosts { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Vote> UserVotes { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string AppUserId { get; set; }

        public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Vote> UserVotes { get; set; }
    }

    // Implements a many-to-many relationship between
    // AppUser and Post.
    public class Vote
    {
        public string AppUserId { get; set; }
        public string PostId { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
        
        public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
        public Post Post { get; set; }
    }

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<AppUser> AppUsers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Vote> Votes { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=.\MSSQL14;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=So63012999")
                .UseLoggerFactory(
                    LoggerFactory.Create(
                        b => b
                            .AddConsole()
                            .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>(
                entity =>
                {
                    entity.HasData(
                        new AppUser {Id = "John"},
                        new AppUser {Id = "Sam"},
                        new AppUser {Id = "Steve"});
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Post>(
                entity =>
                {
                    entity.HasData(
                        new Post
                        {
                            Id = "John-01",
                            AppUserId = "John",
                            Content = "My first post!"
                        },
                        new Post
                        {
                            Id = "Sam-01",
                            AppUserId = "Sam",
                            Content = "What?"
                        },
                        new Post
                        {
                            Id = "Sam-02",
                            AppUserId = "Sam",
                            Content = "Where?"
                        },
                        new Post
                        {
                            Id = "Sam-03",
                            AppUserId = "Sam",
                            Content = "Who?"
                        },
                        new Post
                        {
                            Id = "Steve-01",
                            AppUserId = "Steve",
                            Content = "Are we there yet?"
                        });
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Vote>(
                entity =>
                {
                    entity.HasKey(e => new {e.AppUserId, e.PostId});

                    entity.HasOne(e => e.AppUser)
                        .WithMany(e => e.UserVotes)
                        .HasForeignKey(e => e.AppUserId);

                    entity.HasOne(e => e.Post)
                        .WithMany(e => e.UserVotes)
                        .HasForeignKey(e => e.PostId);

                    entity.HasData(
                        new Vote { AppUserId = "John", PostId = "Sam-01", Value = 1},
                        new Vote { AppUserId = "John", PostId = "Sam-02", Value = 1},
                        new Vote { AppUserId = "John", PostId = "Sam-03", Value = -1},
                        new Vote { AppUserId = "Steve", PostId = "Sam-03", Value = -1});
                });
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            using var context = new Context();

            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            var users = context.AppUsers
                .OrderBy(u => u.Id)
                .ToList();

            var postsWithVotes = context.Votes
                .Include(v => v.Post)
                .ToList();

            var postsWithNegativeVotes = context.Votes
                .Include(v => v.Post)
                .Where(v => v.Value < 0)
                .Select(v => v.Post)
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();
            
            Debug.Assert(users.Count == 3);
            Debug.Assert(postsWithVotes.Count == 4);
            Debug.Assert(postsWithNegativeVotes.Count == 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at the EF Core docs for more information about [Many-To-Many Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) (or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model))).

---

In a real world application, you will also likely need to change the type of your keys from `string` to `int`, `long` or to `Guid`.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I did in my code except I didn't have navigation properties UserVotes in AppUser and Posts. I'm still struggling to read the relationship a bit. Is it "An AppUser can vote for many Posts and a Post can be voted on by many AppUser"?

Comment: Yes, that is how it is. An AppUser can vote for many posts (but only one time for the same post) and a post can be voted on multiple times, but only one time by the same user. If you are having difficulties with a specific query, just explain what you want to query, and I update the sample code accordingly.